# Prove $\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right)$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, proof-verification

*Using the formal definition of convergence of a sequence, show that the sequence converges to 0 as n tends to infinity.*

So we want to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that when $n\geq N$, $$\left|\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|<\epsilon\;.$$

Using the triangle inequality, we obtain:

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\leq\frac{n+1}{n^2} $$

i) From here, is it possible to solve the right hand side explicitly for n in terms of $\epsilon$?

2) Why is it wrong to say that since $n+1\geq\frac{n+1}{n^2}$ for all n, then
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\leq n+1$$ and so then let $\epsilon=n+1$? I can see why 'intuitively' that it shouldn't be right, if $\epsilon$ is a n arbitrary small number then it would make no sense to have $N=\epsilon-1$, but is there some rule that says $N(\epsilon)$ should involve some other operation on $\epsilon?$ For instance, most examples I see are usually like $N=\frac{2}{\epsilon}$, where N gets larger as $\epsilon$ gets smaller, which is what expect.
Also, I can't see where I made an error in my reasoning which led to $N=\epsilon-1$.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is this: **you don't get to choose $\epsilon$**. You have to consider $\epsilon$ as being given to you "by the enemy" -- that is, you need to show that you can make the absolute value smaller than $\epsilon$, *no matter what $\epsilon$ you're given*.

As a hint for how you can do the problem: given $\epsilon>0$, can you choose $n$ so that 
$$
\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}?
$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$\frac1n\pm\frac1{n^2}\le\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}=\frac1n\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le\frac2n$$

for $n\ge 1$.

**Added:** Nicholas R. Peterson has already explained why you can’t let $\epsilon=n+1$. To add just a little to that, remember that you’re trying to show that these terms get close to $0$. If $n=100$, say, knowing that the $100$-th term is less than $101$ really doesn’t help much!

Comment: I think you should address the "...and so then let $\epsilon=n+1$..." part!

Comment: @Peter: Nicholas has already done so, but I am adding a little.

Comment: I mean, as the professor you are! =D

Answer (score 0):

The answers given before me provide you with a nice method to do the exercise but they do not answer your question (i). So this answer will be devoted to help you solving that question which might help you in understanding the theory better.

So, first of all, the answer is: yes, it is possible. You essentially need to solve for what $n$ do we have
$$ \frac{n+1}{n^2} \leq \varepsilon? $$
This comes down to solving a quadratic polynomial if you multiply both sides with $n^2$. I.e. find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, given $\varepsilon>0$, for all $n\geq N$, we have $\varepsilon n^2 - n - 1 \geq 0$.

I hope this helps!